# Server doesn't notice when client closes socket (.NET CF & GPRS)

Tags: .net, sockets, compact-framework, gprs

Client written in .NET Compact Framework.  Client connects a socket to the server over a GPRS connection.  The server accepts the connection.  Client sends 62 bytes of data and then closes the socket.  Server never detects that the client has closed the socket and is therefore not able to know that the transfer has completed.

This code works fine when run over a wireless connection.

Any ideas?

Comment: how you detect in on wireless? by catching exception on receive?

Comment: I assume that the server would detect it the usual way, which is getting 0 bytes returned from a socket read.  At the transport level this is supposed to happen like this: http://penguin.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/academic/networks/transport-layer/tcp/tcp-close.gif.  Since the server is not detecting the close I guess that the server is not receiving the FIN+ACK.